# How to create a Per Request Context for my application

Tags: asp.net-core

I am playing around with the ASP.NET vNext. and I was wondering how to create my own context per request.

In older versions I would create a singleton and store it in `HttpContext.Current.Items`.

The idea is that I want to load some data at the beginning of the request that should be available through the entire request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same with [HttpContext](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http/HttpContext.cs) [Items](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http/HttpContext.cs#L23). You would write a middleware like [this one](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/samples/MvcSample.Web/Monitoring/MonitoringMiddlware.cs) and you can handle your stuff inside the [Invoke](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/d915994f0bd761e81d47207bf57565d556f25d96/samples/MvcSample.Web/Monitoring/MonitoringMiddlware.cs#L27-L50) method.

Comment: Those first 3 links are broken.